# scala splitting json into multipe objects if array valued filed is found

Tags: json, scala, split

I need to split a json object in scala into multiple objects if an array valued fields is found.

input JSON

{
  "name" : "test"
  "age"  : 22,
  "courses" : [math, english] 
}

should be split into

[{
  "name" : "test"
  "age"  : 22,
  "courses" : "math" 
},
{
  "name" : "test"
  "age"  : 22,
  "courses" : "english" 
}]

Are there any frameworks that support this kind of splitting. Thanks!

Comment: No "framework" will support such splitting.

Comment: How can I split it efficiently in scala?

Comment: Did the answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Its best if you model your json to a scala object and then work with it. In this example I am using jackson library and its addon module for scala. You could use any appropriate json library. Here I am modelling your json to a case class using the convenient json to case class deserialization ability provided by the Jackson Scala Module

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper


val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule) 

case class A(name: String, age: Int, courses: Array[String]){def toJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(courses.map(e => A(name,age,Array(e))))}

val json = """{ "name" : "test", "age" : 22, "courses" : ["math", "english"] }"""

val anA = mapper.readValue(json, classOf[A]) 

anA.toJson
```

Comment: Thanks Samar. In real data I cannot model the it as an object. I am thinking if I can scan the object and separate all the array fields first, and later add these array fields to the json in a for loop. I need to get a cartesian product of all the array values in the end. I do not know if there is a better way to achieve this in scala? using map and fold left?

Comment: You will need to parse the json anyways using some json library right?